# Why does an autolayout based NSWindow redraw incorrectly after zooming?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, autolayout

I have created an application from the standard Cocoa application template in Xcode and set it to use automatic reference counting.

All I've added is a toolbar and a table view to the window in MainMenu.xib. If I run the application at this point the application looks like this:

[image]

I then click the green zoom button in the title bar. The window subsequently maximizes and fills the entire desktop. I then click the zoom button again. The window shrinks to the original width but not the original height. It's not as tall as it was when it was maximized, but much taller than the original height:

[image]

I then right-click on the toolbar and hides it. The toolbar animates away but is then immediately visible again. However, the buttons can't be clicked and the window can't be moved by dragging it. It's just as if the toolbar actually deactivated. In order to illustrate it this is what it looks like if the window is resized in this state:

[image]

Why does this happen and what should I do to prevent it? I'm using OS X 10.8 and Xcode 4.4, not the developer previews.

**Update:** (April 2013) It looks like [this is actually a bug in Cocoa](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Aug/msg00152.html). :-(

**Update:** (June 2013) As of 10.8.4 I can no longer reproduce this issue. :-)

Comment: The window isn't redrawing properly - I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to disable "Use Auto Layout" in your .xib files File Inspector,
this is a new function in Xcode 4.4 and might cause your windows behavior.